# can not use gpu with Pytorch on google colab

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

I'd opened a google collaboration notebook to run a python package on it, with the intention to process it using GPU.

Following this [link](https://www.marktechpost.com/2021/01/09/getting-started-with-pytorch-in-google-collab-with-free-gpu/) I selected the GPU option( in the `Runtime` option) and downloaded the needed packages in order to use the GPU with Pytorch and Cuda. however, for some reason, it shows there is a CPU and not GPU.

Installing packages (needed to use conda)

```
!pip install -q condacolab

import condacolab
condacolab.install()
✨✨ Everything looks OK!

!mamba install -c conda-forge scikit-learn 
!mamba install -q openmm
!mamba install -q   pytorch torchvision  cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch 
!mamba install -c rdkit rdkit

!mamba install -q ipykernel 
!mamba install -q matplotlib
```

Connecting to google drive where the .py files with the scripts are:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')

Mounted at /content/drive/
```

but when running this script :

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

It does not recognize.

when running the script below it does not recognize any gpu as well:

```
def try_gpu(i=0): 
    """Return gpu(i) if exists, otherwise return cpu()."""
    if torch.cuda.device_count() >= i + 1:
        return torch.device(f'cuda:{i}')
    return torch.device('cpu')

def try_all_gpus(): 
  """Return all available GPUs, or [cpu(),] if no GPU exists."""
  devices = [
      torch.device(f'cuda:{i}') for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count())]
  return devices if devices else [torch.device('cpu')]

try_gpu(), try_gpu(10), try_all_gpus()
```

the output are all 'cpu' :

```
(device(type='cpu'), device(type='cpu'), [device(type='cpu')])
```

However, when checking if there is GPU with Tenseflow I see there is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
    raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
```

```
Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0
```

I'm not sure if relevant but adding this as well:

```
!nvidia-smi

Mon Jun  7 15:02:40 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.27       Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   77C    P0    33W /  70W |    222MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any ideas\ hints on how to make Pytorch work with GPU on google colab notebook are we be appriciated

Comment: I'm pretty sure `pytorch` is preinstalled with CUDA, no need to mess with the environment

Comment: @ M Z - when trying without installing `Pytorch` I receive this Error : ``import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'``